# Multiple XHDPI Device Resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I need to handle multiple XHDPI devices resolution. As far as i came to know, there are following Dimensions that are falling in XHDPI Range :

- 1184x768
- 1280x720
- 1280x800
- 1224x720

as they all belong to same Dimension, how to differentiate the Resources (drawables) it should load according to screen dimension?

**or**

If I use a single XHDPI layout and place their drawable in xhdpi folder is it sufficient or will this thing disturb the UI

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## XHDPI is a single bucket

### Short Answer:

> A single layout for XHDPI will suffice with their resources placed in
> the proper (xhdpi) drawables folder.

### Long Answer:

Android Devices vary so much, so android decides that these set of screen resolutions fall under one bucket i.e. treated as one device since the variation among themselves is relatively lesser compared to the whole range. Android does runtime image manipulation to adjust your resources a little so that they function as expected.

### Bonus:

To have finer control on images, look at the `Scale` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can read more here

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

basically if you want...you can create folders with the following names:

- layout-sw520dp-port      //Galaxy Note at v4.0.3
  layout-sw520dp-land          layout-sw600dp-port      // Nexus 7
  layout-sw600dp-land          layout-sw700dp-port
  layout-sw700dp-land

etc. etc